# Computer suddenly freezes/stutters or restarts randomly

Tags: windows-10, freeze, desktop-computer, lag

I don't remember when this problem started maybe 1 year or more ago. To be more specific when I open my computer it seems fine for 5 seconds, then it starts getting worse by stuttering for no reason **( even on desktop screen with no major programs running ex. google chrome, games etc. )** or even freezing the whole screen/computer making those weird *bzzzttt..* noises and restarting or even diyng for like **5 - 30 restarts.** It sometimes doesn't even boot up and I'll have to try again in like 3 hours or so. I tried having a **clean windows installation and formatting my computer** but nothing worked. I **tried updating all my programs and drivers** but didn't work either... I also tried putting thermal paste to my cpu...
Don't know whats wrong but maybe you guys can help me since it's pretty a annoying problem that I have on my computer for over a year!

note/edit: ( it also decreases overall perfomance somehow )
[Some information about the topic (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7rm3.png)

Comment: Pretty sure you have a hardware issue. A software issue would have been fixed by the clean install of Windows. Please include some information about your hardware: how many GB of RAM? What model motherboard? What video card, if any?

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities right now. Also try running CoreTemp to see what temperature your CPU idles at, just to rule out overheating.

Comment: @wrecclesham Video Card: NVidia GTX 1050 Ti Gaming X 4GB, 8GB of RAM, Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. H61M-S2V-B3

Answer (score 0):

Try running MemTest86 for at least one entire pass.  It is independent of the operating system on your hard disk.  It is rare, but I did actually have memory go bad after a year of 24/7 constant operation.

If it passes, you might try a Live Linux USB (once again, without touching your existing hard disk--or just remove it from the system to be safe).  If the Live USB OS works reliably, your hard disk or OS on it is messed up.  Buy a new hard disk and install a new OS on it, then copy your old data back as needed from the old hard disk.

Comment: I will need a more explanation cause of hearing this the first time but i'm looking foward to trying it if its the only solution, thanks

Comment: Instead of waiting a long time for a memory scan that's not guaranteed to detect a problem, try removing half the memory, seeing if the problem is fixed. If it still freezes, put that memory back in the same slot as before and remove the other half of the memory and see if the problem goes away. If the problem happens each time, your memory is fine and it's something else.